# imprimir datos en chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

bueno lo que quiero hacer es imprimir el promedio de los 5 tiempos que tengo , esos  5 tiempos los imprime en la grafica sin problemas pero no sé como imprimir el promedio ya que los tiempos los hice con array , por lo que no tengo idea de como hacerlo mismo con el promedio, lo que intente es hacer un ciclo for que hace el promedio pero a la hora de querer imprimirlos solo sale la etiqueta pero no los datos que recoge , cuando pongo un `alert()` si me muestra los promedios.
el promedio que se hace es como se muestra en la imagen,tengo 5 campos que son del t1 hasta el t5 , hago la suma y después lo divido entre 5

```
<?php 
    $host='localhost'; 
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'thanks';
    
    try{
        $pdo = new  PDO("mysql:host=localhost;database=$database", $username, $password);
        
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch (PDOExeption $e){
    
        die("ERROR: could not connect. ".  $e->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>THANKS Digital</title>
        <link style="width:30px;" rel="shortcut icon" href="img/Pr.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/panel-act4.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu-opciones2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/view-activity3.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/i.css">
        
    </head>
    
    
    <?php
    
    $consulta = $_GET['id_registro'];  //creo una variable que trae el id_registro
    // $prov=$_GET['nombre_proveedor'];
    
     $sql1= "SELECT * FROM thanks.act WHERE id_registro = $consulta";  //selecciono los campos necesarios de la tabla con el id_registro
     $result1 = $pdo->query($sql1);
     while ($row1 = $result1->fetch()){
     $proveedor= $row1['nombre_proveedor'];
     $parte= $row1['numero_parte'];
     $calendario= $row1['calendario'];
     }
    try {
        // $sql= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id_registro, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, nombre_proveedor, numero_parte, calendario FROM act WHERE nombre_proveedor = '$proveedor' AND calendario = '$calendario' AND numero_parte ='$parte'");  //selecciono los campos necesarios de la tabla con el id_registro
    
        $sql = "SELECT * from thanks.act WHERE nombre_proveedor = '$proveedor' AND calendario = '$calendario' AND numero_parte ='$parte'"; 
         $result = $pdo->query($sql);
             if($result->rowCount()>0){
               $t1 = array();                       //aqui se crean los arrays
               $t2 = array();
               $t3 = array();
               $t4 = array();
               $t5 = array();
    
                  while ($row = $result->fetch()){
                     $t1[] = $row["t1"];
                     $t2[] = $row["t2"];     //aqui recorre el array llenandolo con datos de la BD 
                     $t3[] = $row["t3"];
                     $t4[] = $row["t4"];
                     $t5[] = $row["t5"];
                   
                     
    
            }unset($result); 
    
        } else {
                echo "no records matching" ; 
        }
    }catch (PDOExeption $e){
        die ("ERROR: could not able to execute $sql. ". $e->getMessage());
    } 
      
    unset($pdo);
    ?>
    <!-- //setup Block  -->
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <canvas id="lineChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"</script>
    
    <button onclick="chartData('bar')">ADD DATASET</button>
    
    
    <script> 
    
    const t1 = <?php echo json_encode($t1); ?>              //pasamos los datos a json
    const t2 = <?php echo json_encode($t2); ?> 
    const t3 = <?php echo json_encode($t3); ?> 
    const t4 = <?php echo json_encode($t4); ?> 
    const t5 = <?php echo json_encode($t5); ?> 
    
    for (var i = 0; i <6; i++) {
       
    let d1= (t1[i]);
    let d2= (t2[i]);
    let d3 =(t3[i]);
    let d4 = (t4[i]);
    let d5 =(t5[i]);
    let d6= (Number(d1)+Number(d2)+Number(d3)+Number(d4)+Number(d5));
     var promedio = d6/5;
    
     
    alert(promedio);
    };
    
    const data = {
    labels: ['REGISTRO 1', 'REGISTRO 2', 'REGISTRO 3', 'REGISTRO 4', 'REGISTRO 5', 'REGISTRO 6'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 't1',
                data: t1,           //en este data se impirmen los datos
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',         //el color de las graficas
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
                label: 't2',
                data: t2,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
                label: 't3',
                data: t3,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
                label: 't4',
                data: t4,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
                label: 't5',
                data: t5,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },{
                label: 'promedio',
                data: promedio,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 128)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }       
            
            ]
        };
    //     const actions = [    //ese codigo es para agregar en la grafica un boton para agregar datos.
    //         {
    //     name: 'Add Data',
    //     handler(chart) {
    //       const data = chart.data;
    //       if (data.datasets.length > 0) {
    //         data.labels = Utils.months({count: data.labels.length + 1});
    
    //         for (var index = 0; index < data.datasets.length; ++index) {
    //           data.datasets[index].data.push(Utils.rand(-100, 100));
    //         }
    
    //         chart.update();
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
    
    //     ];
    
    //     const data2 = {
    // labels: ['Average'],
    //         datasets: [{
    //             label: 'Average',
    //             data2: promedio,
    //             backgroundColor: [
    //                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    //                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    //                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    //                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    //                 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    //                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
    //             ],
    //             borderColor: [
    //                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
    //                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    //                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    //                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    //                 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
    //                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
    //             ],
    //             borderWidth: 1
    //         }
    //         ]};
    //config Block 
    
    const config  = {
    
            type :'bar',
            data, 
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y:{ 
                        beginAtZero: true 
                    }
                }
            }
    };
    
    // const config2  = {
    
    //     type: 'bar',
    //   data,
    //   options: {
    //     indexAxis: 'y',
    //   }
    // };
    
    //Render Block
    const myChart = new Chart (document.getElementById('myChart'),config);  //aqui carga la grafica y la imprime en pantalla
    
    // const lineChart = new Chart (document.getElementById('lineChart'),config2);
    
    function chartData(data){
        myChart.config.data = data
        myChart.update();
    }
    
    </script> 
    <section>
    
    <div class="save1">             <!--    el botón para ir hacia atras -->
    <form action="principal.php">
            <button  class="back">
                BACK
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
            </section>
            </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuantos registros regresa tu consulta? ya que tienes un bucle for en js y solo se muestran 5 registros... promedio se inicializa dentro de tu bucle for por lo que se sobrescribe por cada iteracion

Comment: tengo 7 de prueba per los filtro y me deja con 3 solo que el ultimo tiene valore pequeños y no se alcanza a ver en la captura.

Comment: el promedio que intentas mostrar es el promedio global de todos los registros? podrias agregar la data  devuelta de la consulta es que no logro comprenderte todavia!

Comment: o que quiero mostrar es un promedio por cada registro y cada registro tiene sus 5 datos que son el t1,t2,t3,t4,t5. , en el alert(); si me los muestra pero a la hora de querer imprimirlos en la grafica no salen , solo se crea el espacio al lado de los datos y el label de arriba , pero ningun error se muestra.

Comment: entonces solo debes sacar fuera del for a d6 ejemplo `let d6 =[]; for (var i = 0; i <6; i++) {  d6.push( (Number(d1)+Number(d2)+Number(d3)+Number(d4)+Number(d5))/5) ` y eso seria todo!

Comment: para que colocas 2 for?  debes eliminar el segundo for ` let d6 =[]; for (var i = 0; i <6; i++) { 
let d1= (t1[i]);
let d2= (t2[i]);
let d3 =(t3[i]);
let d4 =(t4[i]);
let d5 =(t5[i]);
d6.push( (Number(d1)+Number(d2)+Number(d3)+Number(d4)+Number(d5))/5);
}`

Comment: sí ,no había leído bien , ya funciono , como decías solo era sacar el d6